# Find by relation in php-activerecord

Tags: php, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I'm trying on php-activerecord for a project – I've used it before in Lithium and CodeIgniter – but I am stuck at something that I think should be pretty easy. But I simply can not wrap my head around it.

So, I've got two tables:

```
post       |id  |title  |content
           ----------------------
           |1   |Test   |Lorem...
```

and:

```
post_meta  |id  |post_id  |publish_date
           ----------------------------
           | 1  |1        |2013-03-23
```

Now, if I would like to match the `title` in the post table, and the `publish_date` in the post_meta-table – how would I go about in the simplest and most elegant way?

As it stands now I seem to have to do two separate queries, first at the meta table to extract the posts with the correct publish_date – and then loop through that one until I find a matching title. Or I can use relationships (`$has_one` and `$belongs_to`) – but that way it feels like I am doing it the "other way around" when I want to extract my post-data (`$postMetas->post->content`).

Feel free to come up with ideas and solutions – or even alternatives to an ORM that makes this is simple and elegant as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use a joined structure in a finder. Check out [this part of the manual](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/projects/main/wiki/Finders#joins).

Basically, it says you can join using known connections, and use those as base for what you get returned. The books examples on that page are quite good, see:

```
# fetch all books joining their corresponding author
 7 $book = Book::all(array('joins' => array('author')));
 8 # sql => SELECT `books`.* FROM `books`
 9 #      INNER JOIN `authors` ON(`books`.author_id = `authors`.id)
```